# Is it possible within Apache or a CGI script to tell if the request was redirected from domain xyz.com (301 redirect)?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, cgi, referrer

I have a CGI script that sometimes has people arriving there redirected from a 301 redirect from a URL at another domain.

I have made a trial run with http://default.jonathanscorner.com/project/redirector to redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^/project/redirector$ http://jonathanscorner.com/project/printenv.cgi [R=301,L]
```

http://jonathanscorner.com/project/printenv.cgi is just what its name would suggest:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Content-type: text/plain'
echo ''
printenv
```

The environmental variables printed by the CGI script do not seem to reference the originating domain, default.jonathanscorner.com:

```
SERVER_SIGNATURE=<address>Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at jonathanscorner.com Port 80</address>

HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
SERVER_PORT=80
HTTP_HOST=jonathanscorner.com
DOCUMENT_ROOT=/home/cjsh/mirror
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/home/cjsh/mirror/project/printenv.cgi
REQUEST_URI=/project/printenv.cgi
SCRIPT_NAME=/project/printenv.cgi
SCRIPT_URI=http://jonathanscorner.com/project/printenv.cgi
HTTP_CONNECTION=keep-alive
REMOTE_PORT=54506
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
SCRIPT_URL=/project/printenv.cgi
PWD=/home/cjsh/mirror/project
SERVER_ADMIN=CJSHayward@POBox.com
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE=en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6
HTTP_ACCEPT=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
REMOTE_ADDR=98.253.179.182
SHLVL=1
SERVER_NAME=jonathanscorner.com
SERVER_SOFTWARE=Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
QUERY_STRING=
SERVER_ADDR=69.163.221.78
GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING=gzip,deflate,sdch
REQUEST_METHOD=GET
HTTP_COOKIE=__atuvc=10%7C25%2C10%7C26%2C5%7C27%2C33%7C28
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

It doesn't look like the information I want can be obtained that way.

Are there other ways to detect if one was redirected from a particular domain to the new domain? If site xyz.com links to http://default.jonathanscorner.com/project/redirector and that redirects to http://jonathanscorner.com/project/printenv.cgi, from Apache's point of view is the referrer domain http://default.jonathanscorner.com/project/redirector or the xyz.com URL?

Can it be done from Apache config?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to set the domain statically (following example uses set of 2 domains) then you can try adding the following to .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(domain1|domain2)(\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www.%1%2/$1 [L]
```